# One to Many Relationship not working! Entity doesn't save the foreign key. Spring Boot

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot, orm, entity-relationship

I am new to spring boot and relationships and I have json data that is passed into controller and then I have 3 different entities that it needs to go however the data is going but the table wont show the foreign key below is the json data`
{

```
"orderId": "ORD00001",
"orderReferenceCode": "ABCD",
"messageId": "EDI238473828384",
"messageType": "MORR",
"messageCreatedAt": "2018-01-10T10:56:00Z",
"shipToLocationId": "34rsdf",
"shipToAddressName": "Test Store",
"shipToAddressLine1": "1 Order Street",
"shipToAddressLine2": "",
"shipToAddressCity": "asdfa",
"shipToAddressState": "sadfasdf",
"shipToAddressPostCode": "423d23",
"shipToAddressCountryCode": "UK",
"shipToDeliverAt": "2016-08-25",
"shipToDeliverLatestAt": "2018-01-12",
"items": [
    {
        "itemId": "106571637",
        "itemLineId": 1,
        "itemBaseType": "skuMin",
        "itemAlternateId": {
            "skuMin": "M104593859",
            "skuPin": "P104593867",
            "skuLegacy": "L0472851",
            "barcodeAsin": "ASIN29384845",
            "barcodeEan": "EAN3928445",

        },
        "itemDescription": "Heinz Baked Beans",
        "quantityType": "unit",
        "quantityOrdered": 30,
        "priceOrderedCurrency": "GBP",
        "priceOrderedAmount": 1.34,
        "priceOrderedTaxRate": 20,

    }
]}
```

Next up I Have 3 Entities for each table Item, Order and ItemAlternateId

Order Entity

```
@Data
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "order_table")
public class Order {

    private @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    long id;
    private String orderId;
    private String orderReferenceCode;
    private String messageId;
    private String messageType;
    private String messageCreatedAt; // Date
    private String shipToLocationId;
    private String shipToAddressName;
    private String shipToAddressLine1;
    private String shipToAddressLine2;
    private String shipToAddressCity;
    private String shipToAddressState;
    private String shipToAddressPostCode;
    private String shipToAddressCountryCode;
    private String shipToDeliverAt; // Date
    private String shipToDeliverLatestAt; // Date
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "orderedBy")
    private List<Item> items;

    public Order(String orderId, String orderReferenceCode, String messageId, String messageType, String messageCreatedAt, String shipToLocationId, String shipToAddressName, String shipToAddressLine1, String shipToAddressLine2, String shipToAddressCity, String shipToAddressState, String shipToAddressPostCode, String shipToAddressCountryCode, String shipToDeliverAt, String shipToDeliverLatestAt, List<Item> items) {
        this.orderId = orderId;
        this.orderReferenceCode = orderReferenceCode;
        this.messageId = messageId;
        this.messageType = messageType;
        this.messageCreatedAt = messageCreatedAt;
        this.shipToLocationId = shipToLocationId;
        this.shipToAddressName = shipToAddressName;
        this.shipToAddressLine1 = shipToAddressLine1;
        this.shipToAddressLine2 = shipToAddressLine2;
        this.shipToAddressCity = shipToAddressCity;
        this.shipToAddressState = shipToAddressState;
        this.shipToAddressPostCode = shipToAddressPostCode;
        this.shipToAddressCountryCode = shipToAddressCountryCode;
        this.shipToDeliverAt = shipToDeliverAt;
        this.shipToDeliverLatestAt = shipToDeliverLatestAt;
        this.items.forEach(item -> item.setOrderedBy(this));
    }
}
```

Item Entity

```
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@Data
public class Item {

    private @Id @GeneratedValue long id;
    private String itemId;
    private int itemLineId;
    private String itemBaseType;
    @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private ItemAlternateId itemAlternateId;
    private String itemDescription;
    private String quantityType;
    private int quantityOrdered;
    private String priceOrderedCurrency;
    private double priceOrderedAmount;
    private int priceOrderedTaxRate;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "order_id")
    private Order orderedBy;

    public Item(String itemId, int itemLineId, String itemBaseType, ItemAlternateId itemAlternateId, String itemDescription, String quantityType, int quantityOrdered, String priceOrderedCurrency, double priceOrderedAmount, int priceOrderedTaxRate) {
        this.itemId = itemId;
        this.itemLineId = itemLineId;
        this.itemBaseType = itemBaseType;
        this.itemAlternateId = itemAlternateId;
        this.itemDescription = itemDescription;
        this.quantityType = quantityType;
        this.quantityOrdered = quantityOrdered;
        this.priceOrderedCurrency = priceOrderedCurrency;
        this.priceOrderedAmount = priceOrderedAmount;
        this.priceOrderedTaxRate = priceOrderedTaxRate;
    }
}
```

ItemAlternateId Entity

```
@Entity
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class ItemAlternateId {
    private @Id @GeneratedValue long id;
    private String skuMin;
    private String skuPin;
    private String skuLegacy;
    private String barcodeAsin;
    private String barcodeEan;
    @OneToOne
    private Item item;
}
```

My OrderController

```
@RestController
public class OrderController {

    @Autowired
    private OrderService orderService;



    @GetMapping("/orders/{id}")
    public Order getOneOrder(@PathVariable Long id) {
        return orderService.getOneOrder(id);
    }

    @PostMapping("/orders")
    public Order newOrder(@RequestBody Order order) {
        return orderService.save(order);
    }
}
```

OrderService has this function which would basically call repository interface and it just saves the object.

```
 public Order save(Order order)
    {
        return orderRepository.save(order);
    }
```

Everything works other than the fact that in Item table and ItemAlternateId table it doesnt save the foreign key.

The json returned look like this

```
{
    "id": 10,
    "orderId": "ORD00001",
    "orderReferenceCode": "ABCD",
    "messageId": "EDI238473828384",
    "messageType": "MORR",
    "messageCreatedAt": "2018-01-10T10:56:00Z",
    "shipToLocationId": "GLN999999",
    "shipToAddressName": "Test Store",
    "shipToAddressLine1": "1 Order Street",
    "shipToAddressLine2": "",
    "shipToAddressCity": "Leeds",
    "shipToAddressState": "West Yorkshire",
    "shipToAddressPostCode": "LS1 9PP",
    "shipToAddressCountryCode": "UK",
    "shipToDeliverAt": "2016-08-25",
    "shipToDeliverLatestAt": "2018-01-12",
    "items": [
        {
            "id": 11,
            "itemId": "106571637",
            "itemLineId": 1,
            "itemBaseType": "skuMin",
            "itemAlternateId": {
                "id": 12,
                "skuMin": "M104593859",
                "skuPin": "P104593867",
                "skuLegacy": "L0472851",
                "barcodeAsin": "ASIN29384845",
                "barcodeEan": "EAN3928445",
                "item": null
            },
            "itemDescription": "Heinz Baked Beans",
            "quantityType": "unit",
            "quantityOrdered": 30,
            "priceOrderedCurrency": "GBP",
            "priceOrderedAmount": 1.34,
            "priceOrderedTaxRate": 20,
            "orderedBy": null
        }
    ]
}
```

---

**update**

I have managed to fix this issue by using @JsonManagedReference on One to many relationship and @JsonBackReference on many to one relationship so

Item Entity

```
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "order_id")
    @JsonBackReference
    private Order orderedBy;
```

Order Entity

```
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "orderedBy")
    @JsonManagedReference
    private List<Item> items;
```